# Don't Display NULL value When quantity is greater than 1

Tags: sql, select, view, null

I am quite new to sql so sorry if this seems really simple.

I am struggling to detail the question and I'm not sure of the right functionality to use.

I have a table that contains product ID's (column A) and if that product ID has different options (small, medium, large or 10cm, 20cm, 30cm or blue, black green etc..) there is another column populated (column b) which provides the attribute product ID. Unfortunately, the column sometimes provides a null value even when you have to choose an attribute (i.e. you can't say that you don't want a size or colour).

What I am trying to create is a view where the row is displayed if there is only 1 option (column b will always be NULL) and also display the row if there is an option to display (excluding any NULL values in column B)

Here is an example of the data that I am using, you can see near the bottom 1964 & 1980 have attribute ID's but no other NULL values where as 7487 & 7880 have both NULL and attribute ID's.

| Products_ID | AttributeID |
| --- | --- |
| 7487 |  |
| 7487 | 7487-19341 |
| 7880 | 7880-19347 |
| 7880 |  |
| 1954 |  |
| 1954 | 1954-9318 |
| 7246 |  |
| 7246 | 7246-18205 |
| 2313 |  |
| 4861 |  |
| 6474 |  |
| 6756 |  |
| 6960 |  |
| 6960 | 6960-18463 |
| 5919 |  |
| 5919 | 5919-14569 |
| 947 |  |
| 2320 |  |
| 2320 | 2320-3561 |
| 7742 |  |
| 3070 |  |
| 3070 | 3070-17697 |
| 7702 |  |
| 1964 | 1964-2469-2475 |
| 2869 |  |
| 2869 | 2869-14506 |
| 1980 | 1980-2412-5795 |
| 6783 |  |
| 6783 | 6783-18310 |
| 7816 |  |
| 1815 |  |
| 1815 | 1815-1667 |

This is what I want to be displayed

| Products_ID | AttributeID |
| --- | --- |
| 7487 | 7487-19341 |
| 7880 | 7880-19347 |
| 1954 | 1954-9318 |
| 7246 | 7246-18205 |
| 2313 |  |
| 4861 |  |
| 6474 |  |
| 6756 |  |
| 6960 | 6960-18463 |
| 5919 | 5919-14569 |
| 947 |  |
| 2320 | 2320-3561 |
| 7742 |  |
| 3070 | 3070-17697 |
| 7702 |  |
| 1964 | 1964-2469-2475 |
| 2869 | 2869-14506 |
| 1980 | 1980-2412-5795 |
| 6783 | 6783-18310 |
| 7816 |  |
| 1815 | 1815-1667 |

Comment: I have just realised that the values are not NULL they are blank. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you only want `NULL` values if there are no other values for the product in the table.  If so:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.attributeid is not null or
      not exists (select 1
                  from t tt2
                  where t2.productid = t.productid and
                        t2.attributeid is not null
                 );
```

If there is at most one non-null attribute per product, you can also use aggregation:

```
select productid, max(attributeid)
from t
group by productid;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT T.*
  FROM [test].[dbo].[Stock] as t
where t.[product_attribute_combo] <> '' or
      not exists (select 1
                  from [test].[dbo].[Stock] as t2
                  where t2.[products_id] = t.[products_id] and
                        t2.[product_attribute_combo] <> ''
                 );
GO
```